# Why does 'a' > 'A' evaluates to True in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, char, string-comparison

I am learning about logical operators in Python. Why does the above expression evaluates to True.

Answer (score 2):

Because each Unicode character is associated with a code point value:

`ord('a')` is 97

and

`ord('A')` is 65

See [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) and [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)